# Auto-update server

Tags: python, python-3.x, server

Yesterday and today I've been working on an auto-update system for a game project. I've just pushed the server-side script to the server, and it seems to work great. Since this is public-facing code, though, I certainly wouldn't mind a few more eyes on it before I actually deploy it and changes get exponentially more painful.

It's intended to be used by multiple client applications at once; one text file per application. Later revisions might include some way to download previous versions, hence why their paths are stored in the file.

```
'''
Created on Nov 3, 2014

@author: Schilcote

Protocol:

1. Client opens TCP connection to server @ port 7363
2. Client pushes version code (hash, build date, version number, arbitrary id; implementation irrelevant) followed by newline to server
3a. If version code invalid, connection assumed to be hostile (port scan), connection is closed, server MAY ban IP
3b. If version code valid and most recent, connection is closed
3c. If version code valid and not most recent, MD5 hash of new version archive sent to client
4. Client prepares to receive update file and sends one byte, 0x06 (ASCII ACK) to server
5. Server transmits archive to client and closes connection.

The version ID __latest__ is reserved; do not use it.

Client should, of course, check the MD5 hash against the downloaded file before overwriting itself.

Server reads ids and filenames from version files. These files have the following format:

versionid:filename [newline]

One versionid-filename pair per line. Data file should not contain leading or trailing whitespace.
First line is assumed to be the most recent version; this is what will be pushed downstream.
'''

import socketserver
import hashlib
import glob
import os.path
import collections
import datetime

class AutoUpdateHandler(socketserver.StreamRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        instream = self.rfile
        outstream = self.wfile
        print("Handling request from ",self.client_address[0],"@",datetime.datetime.now(),".")
        version=instream.readline().decode("ASCII").strip("\n")
        print("Client running version ID",version)

        archive=None
        for thevdata in vdatas:
            try:
                thevdata[version]
                print("Valid ID; maps to",archive)
                latest=thevdata["__latest__"]
                if version==latest:
                    print("Client has latest version. Closing connection.")
                    return
                else:
                    print("Version ID",latest,"is more recent.")
                    archive=thevdata[latest]
                    break
            except KeyError:
                pass

        if not archive:
            print("Invalid version ID. Closing connection.")
            #ban(self.client_address[0])
            return

        with open(archive, "rb") as archivehandle:
            #Grab the entire contents of the file
            data=archivehandle.read()

        print("Sending hash.")
        #Create a hasher, fill it with data, and grab the digest
        hash=hashlib.md5(data).digest()
        outstream.write(hash)

        #Now wait for ACK (0x06)
        if not instream.read(1) == b'\x06':
            print("Invalid hash acceptance code (client should send 0x06).")
            return

        print("Sending ",archive,"...")
        #Finally, push the entire contents of the archive down the pipe
        outstream.write(data)
        print("Done @ ",datetime.datetime.now(),".\n")
        return

def load_versions(filename):
    "Load version data file into a dict mapping versionids to filenames and returns said dict."

    versions=collections.OrderedDict()
    with open(filename,"r") as file:
        latest=None
        for line in file:
            line=line.strip()
            version, archivename = line.split(":")
            versions[version]=archivename
            if not latest:
                #first line read is considered latest version
                latest=version
                versions["__latest__"]=latest
    return versions

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global vdatas
    vdatas=[]
    print("Server starting @",datetime.datetime.now(),".")
    print("Preparing to load version data.")
    vdglob = glob.glob("*.txt")
    for thefilename in vdglob:
        print("Loading version data from",thefilename,"...")
        vdata=load_versions(thefilename)
        vdatas.append(vdata)
        print("Loaded",len(vdata)-1,"id-file pairs.")
    print("")
    print("Initializing & grabbing port.")
    server=socketserver.ThreadingTCPServer(("localhost",7363), AutoUpdateHandler)
    print("Accepting connections...")
    server.serve_forever()
    print("Server shutting down @",datetime.datetime.now(),"...")
```

I'm not particularly concerned with style criticisms (I know, the imports are in the wrong order & I should be using str.format), though I'll accept them; I'm more looking for potentially dangerous edge-cases I missed or clearly stupid decisions I made. Oh, and I'm aware md5 isn't really intended for what I'm using it for and not recommended for its intended purpose anyway; by the time I remembered that the code was already written and unless I'm very mistaken, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

- You may want to wrap everything from line 69

  ```
  with open(archive, "rb") as archivehandle:
  ```

  to line 81

  ```
  outstream.write(data)
  ```

  into a `try ... except IOError` clause. If `open` fails, there's not much sense to use with `data`.
- The line 47

  ```
  thevdata[version]
  ```

  should probably read

  ```
  archive = thevdata[version]
  ```

  I gather it is a copy-paste problem.
- A hostile (or buggy) client may never send `ACK`, leaving the connection indefinitely open (a trivial DDOS attack). Implement timeouts.